# Getting the 75% value of a candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

If the candle `open` is 10 and the `close` is 8. The value at 50% would be 9, how to algorithm the value at other percentages such as 75%/80%/85%..etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without knowing the exact syntax of this function, the calculation inside this function should be like this

```
price(percentage) => (open > close) ? (close+(open-close)*percentage/100) : (open+(close-open)*percentage/100)
```

or

```
if (open > close) then
 return (close+(open-close)*percentage/100)
else
 return (open+(close-open)*percentage/100)
```

percentage as float value between 0...100